# Enable placeholder in input field such that it empties 'after' user input as opposed to onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the placeholder attribute for HTML input[type=text] elements such that the placeholder text disappears 'after' the user starts typing as opposed to 'onfocus'. Something like the sign-in page on pivotal tracker: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/signin

So far I've not used the placeholder attribute. Instead I used a 'onkeyup' event on the input field such that it empties the contents of the input field as soon as the user types the first character. To do this I've setup a custom attribute on the input element called 'data-received' which is false by default and is set to true as soon as the user types the first character. (So that it doesnt continue to empty the field). I can do something similar by 'unbinding' the 'keyup' method on the input field.

I m not so happy with this method and I was wondering if there s a better way to do this?

Comment: I'd approach the exact same way you've described. One potential downside I can see is that a right-click + paste operation wouldn't trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. I took some cues from the zendesk site as well. Firstly a placeholder attribute is not used. A label is used along with the input field with position: absolute. Its position to overlap the input field associated with it. Javascript is used to track the onkeyup event and as soon as it sees that the value of the input field is not empty, it simply hides the associated label. If you delete whatever your typed, it shows the label again :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a `placeholder` attribute but it may not work in all browsers.

[HTML5 Placeholder Input Fields Fixed with jQuery](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) has a fix that makes it work in all browsers.

jQuery plugins that do this

- http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/
- http://www.iliadraznin.com/2011/02/jquery-placeholder-plugin/

Comment: as i mentioned in my question, the placeholder shud work such that, it clears the input field 'after' user starts typing... not 'onfocus'

Comment: It does. What browser are you using?

Comment: I m using FF, as you can see on that page itself, the author is only using onfocus and onblur to simulate placeholder functionality. I need it to work 'after' the user types in. So if the user clicks in the textfield, the placeholder text is still visible. He types first character then the placeholder text is not visible.

Comment: Updated with a couple of jQuery plugins. See if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Check out:

- [Cross Browser HTML5 Placeholder Text](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text) ([DEMO](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-placeholder-text/))

The `placeholder` attribute is used (if not using JS) but see above link to do it in a cross browser way.

Comment: as i mentioned in my question, the placeholder shud work such that, it clears the input field 'after' user starts typing... not 'onfocus'. none of the examples on that page do this.